# How to access the $http service request object in Angular JS?

Tags: angularjs, angular-http

I am making an http request using the $http service as follows :

```
$http({
        url: "URL",
        method: "POST",
        data: payload,
        headers :{
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
            "access_token": xyz
        }                
    }).then(function (response) {
        $log.debug("Response :",response);
    }, function (error) {
        $log.debug("error :",error);
    });
```

I need to access the request object(along with the headers,etc.) that I sent over. Is it possible in code?

Comment: you wish to hook each http request and add your csrf token?

Comment: I wanted to access the headers I had used in the request programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an [interceptor](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http). Here is a [good article](http://www.webdeveasy.com/interceptors-in-angularjs-and-useful-examples/) and an example from it.

```
module.factory('timestampMarker', [function() {  
    var timestampMarker = {
        request: function(config) {
            config.requestTimestamp = new Date().getTime();
            return config;
        },
        response: function(response) {
            response.config.responseTimestamp = new Date().getTime();
            return response;
        }
    };
    return timestampMarker;
}]);

module.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {  
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push('timestampMarker');
}]);
```

Using an interceptor will give you the ability to read into or add headers to the request, etc. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You can see the request properties like in the example:

```
$http.post('/service', params).success(
    function(data, status, headers, config) {
        //...
        console.log('properties', config.method, config.headers['Content-Type'], config);
});
```

or if you want to see/change properties before/after request in more global way you can use interceptors:

```
app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push(['$q', function($q) {
        return {
            'request': function(config) {
                // for example:
                config.headers['Content-Type'] = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded';
                // same more logic ...

                return config;
            },
            'response': function(response) {
                // for example:
                if (!response.data || !response.data.status) {
                    return $q.reject(response);
                }
                // same more logic ...

                return response;
            },
            'responseError': function(rejection) {
                // same more logic ...
            }
        };
    }]);
}]);
```